# Combine JavaScript regex's into one

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to combine these JavaScript regex's into a single regex. How can I do this? I have tried using the '|' operator in-between strings, but this does not work.

```
var r1 = new RegExp(id + '\\s*===\\s*TRUE', 'gm');
var r2 = new RegExp(id + '\\s*===\\s*true', 'gm');
var r3 = new RegExp(id + '\\s*===\\s*FALSE', 'gm');
var r4 = new RegExp(id + '\\s*===\\s*false', 'gm');
var r5 = new RegExp(id + '\\s*!==\\s*TRUE', 'gm');
var r6 = new RegExp(id + '\\s*!==\\s*true', 'gm');
var r7 = new RegExp(id + '\\s*!==\\s*FALSE', 'gm');
var r8 = new RegExp(id + '\\s*!==\\s*false', 'gm');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this specific case

```
new RegExp(id + '\\s*[!=]==\\s*(?:TRUE|true|false|FALSE)', 'gm')
```

should do the trick.

In the general case, joining the strings with '|' should work.

@Kolink's answer is better if you also want to accept 'fAlSe' and similar strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var r = new RegExp(id+"\\s*[!=]==\\s*(?:true|false)","gi");
```

I removed the `m` modifier, since it doesn't apply here, and added the `i` modifier to take care of all case options.

Comment: How come you remove the extra escape on the "\s". When I use your regex I no longer match strings like "DEF === TRUE". Is there something I don't know here?

Comment: @Kolink: I edited your answer to include an escape to the `\`.